# apt-puppetlabs do repos first

Tags: puppet, apt, hiera

on my puppetserver i use the puppetlabs-apt module to configure the repos. And i use hiera to get the data for the repos. If i run it i get the message that dirmngr cant be installed cause it cant be found in the repos. 
That error comes because puppet is trying to install dirmngr before hes doing the repos. And dirmngr is required in the module.

Is there a way to force the the module to do the repos first and then let it install dirmngr?

my code is like this

```
class {'apt':
purge =>{
"/etc/apt/sources.list =>true",
},
}
```

Comment: It would be great to get some feedback on the below answer @user3045725. I want to ensure it's correct, or otherwise edit it.

Comment: Is this MR related to your issue ? [key: Don't include dirmngr unless necessary](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/pull/855)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you should be able to do something like this:

```puppet
$dirmngr_apt_source = ...

class { 'apt':
  purge => {
    "/etc/apt/sources.list" => true
  }
}

Apt::Source[$dirmngr_apt_source] -> Package['dirmngr']
```

Further explanation:

- The variable `$dirmngr_apt_source` is for you to fill in with the Apt source that the dirmngr package lives in. (Full disclaimer: I don't know much about Ubuntu.)
- Although the Apt class declares the resources `Apt::Source[$dirmngr_apt_source]` and `Package['dirmngr']`, you can still declare relationships between those resources from outside the class, as I did there.

Also, this is a bit of a hack in my opinion, and it sounds like this is possibly a bug or a design flaw in the Apt module.

That is to say, considering that the Apt module manages a Linux node's Apt sources, and the dirmngr package depends on Apt sources, there shouldn't be an assumption in the module that the dirmngr package can be found prior to configuration of the Apt sources. (Or if it's a valid assumption, then perhaps it needs better documentation?)

So, you might consider raising a bug or checking if there's already a bug.